# How to replace some words in bracket with html tag in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to replace some words between bracket with html tag. Thing I have is,

```
$string = "Please make it (yellow)! (Red) also ok. I think, you like (blue)";
```

Thing I want is,

```
$string = "Please make it <span class='font-bold'>(yellow)</span>! <span class='font-bold'>(Red)</span> also ok. I think, you like <span class='font-bold'>(blue)</span>";
```

If I would like to replace text not only in brackets, but also in something like **"[text]","{text}",QtextQ**, how can I do?

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to become familiar with str_replace (http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

Here's how you would do it:

```
$pattern = ["(",")"];
$replace = ["<span class='bold-face'>(",")</span>"];

$newstring = str_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);
```

Also check out preg_replace (http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for regular expression string replacements for even more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's your task and you should try to solve it first before asking, and should provide what you have done so far.

Basically you have to find `()` with text in the middle, the best way is using regular expression pattern to find it.

### Here solution using [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$string = 'Please make it (yellow)! (Red) also ok. I think, you like (blue)';
$pattern = '/(\(\w+\))/';
$replacement = '<span class=="font-bold=">${1}</span>';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

for **[]** **{}** **QQ** change pattern to this `/(\(\w+\)|\[\w+\]|{\w+}|Q\w+Q)/`